# Spark UDF to custom sort array of structs

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use a UDF to sort an array of structs based on a custom ordering that I have defined.

Here is an example of the type of result I'm looking to get:

```
input_tbl
+-------+-------+------+
| id1   | id2   | num  |
+-------+-------+------+
|   1   |   2   |  1   |
|   1   |   3   | -3   |
|   1   |   4   |  2   |
+-------+-------+------+

output_tbl
+-------+-------+------+
| id1   | id2   | num  |
+-------+-------+------+
|   1   |   3   | -3   |
+-------+-------+------+
```

Some example code for the case class and UDF are shown below.

```
case class Score(id: String, num: Int) extends Ordered[Score] {

  def compare(that: Score): Int = {
    abs(this.num-that.num)
  }
}

val toScoreType : UserDefinedFunction = udf((id: String, num: Int) => {
    Score(id, num)
})

val sortScoreList: UserDefinedFunction = udf((score_list: Array[Score]) => {
    score_list.sorted
})
```

And I am calling the sortScore UDF as follows:

```
val temp = input_tbl
    .select('id1, toScoreType('id2, 'num).as("score"))
    .groupBy('id1)
    .agg((collect_set('score)).as("score_list"))


temp.select('id1, sortScoreList('score_list).as("result"))
```

However, I'm getting an "java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef" error.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark cannot map to records (structs) to case classes as inputs for UDFs. Actually your function `toScoreType` will not convert to case classes (check data schema!), internally its just a struct again (i.e a `Row`).

You should rewrite your code to use a single UDF:

```
val sortScoreList: UserDefinedFunction = udf((score_list: Seq[Row]) => {
  score_list.map{case Row(id:String,num:Int) => Score(id,num)}.sorted
})


val temp = input_tbl
  .groupBy('id1)
  .agg((collect_set(struct('id2,'num))).as("score_list"))

temp.select('id1, sortScoreList('score_list).as("result")).show()
```

But this will not give the desired result:

```
+---+--------------------+
|id1|              result|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[[2, 1], [3, -3],...|
+---+--------------------+
```

If you want a single record, your UDF should one return 1 case class, such as:

```
val sortScoreList: UserDefinedFunction = udf((score_list: Seq[Row]) => {
  score_list.map{case Row(id:String,num:Int) => Score(id,num)}.sorted.head
})
```

And then convert your struct a columns:

```
temp.select('id1, sortScoreList('score_list).as("result"))
  .select($"id1",$"result.*")
  .show()
```

EDIT:

To get your desired result, I would do it like this:

```
case class Score(id: String, num: Int)

val sortScoreList: UserDefinedFunction = udf((score_list: Seq[Row]) => {
      score_list.map{case Row(id:String,num:Int) => Score(id,num)}.minBy(_.num)
 })


temp.select('id1, sortScoreList('score_list).as("result"))
  .select($"id1",$"result.*")
  .show()

+---+---+---+
|id1| id|num|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  3| -3|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: @mk2020 Added suggestion to get your desired result